# How to change submitLabel of TextField as the user types

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I'm trying to make the submit button of a TextField to read "done" when there is no text, which would result in nothing happening, but also read "search" when there is text, which would perform a search. I tried to use a ternary operator in the .submitLabel modifier to do this, but it does not change dynamically, only when the user closes out and reopens the TextField.

```
TextField("Search for meals...", text: $searchText)
        .submitLabel(searchText != "" ? .search : .done)
```

Comment: Please edit you question and post a [mcve]